# Why code files of an open source library are different in github repo and node_modules

Tags: javascript, npm, open-source

I installed lodash module and wanted to look at their code and I  noticed that the file structure and the code in my node_modules are different from what is in their github repo.
I mean if I install the library and also clone their repo the code will be different. Can someone explain to me why they are different?
Is it because of build process that changes the file structure? If yes, is there a way I can take the code from repo and create the “bundled” version?

I’m asking these questions because for example in “lodash” repo there is no “build” command but still the code in node_modules is different than their code in repo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing the [README](https://github.com/lodash/lodash#readme) tells you:

> Generated using [lodash-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-cli):
>
> ```
> $ npm run build
> $ lodash -o ./dist/lodash.js
> $ lodash core -o ./dist/lodash.core.js
> ```

… is that the build tool is in a different package.

Comment: Thanks, don’t know how could I miss that.